# Why does Thunar suddenly see SD card as empty?

Tags: sd-card, 5.1-lollipop, linux, mtp

For several days, I have been able to access the SD card of my phone from Thunar having installed libmtp via MTP. Now, when I go to Thunar to mount my phone, it does not show the files inside the SD card.

- Thunar correctly reports that the SD card has several GB of used and free space, so it knows there are files on the SD card.
- Thunar shows no files on the SD card.
- If I connect with adb, I can browse to the SD card and see the data is still there.
- I can use Thunar to still browse the internal storage of the phone.
- I am not aware of changing any settings to have caused this to occur.
- The phone and SD card are brand new.

What might have caused this change in behavior?

Comment: It's just MTP being MTP. Probably the media scanner forgot about the contents of the SD card or is just re-indexing it and the database is inaccessible to the MTP application.

Comment: @GiantTree MTP is horrendous in this aspect.

Comment: Is there some way to fix it?